# How do I remove Project Server 2010 once installed into the SharePoint 2010 Farm?

Tags: administration, maintenance

I'm sure the information for such an administrative task is out there. I'm just having trouble finding it. Any one know where this particular piece of documentation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Project 2007, it's not supported to uninstall Project from a farm because the Database Schema is updated.

Removing it anyway may reset all your IIS customizations as well, as well as creating problems / inconsistencies with your SP farm.

What is the purpose of uninstalling it?

Comment: My purpose is to remove services that are not used. It was installed but now is not required. I can't believe that it is an unsupported feature.

Comment: You can disable the project services without uninstalling Project.